# How to set a password to protect a directory and its contents in unix?

Tags: unix

May I know how to set a password to protect a directory and its contents in unix? Eg. It will prompt user to type in a password to access the directory.

I tried to do it with enfs:

```
mkdir ~/.encrypted ~/encrypted
encfs ~/.encrypted ~/encrypted
```

And but it shows "encfs: command not found".

Comment: doing a quick search resulted in one of hundreds site explaining/showing how to do this, depending on flavor of unix, encryption tools needs to be install, see this site,  https://medium.com/geoblinktech/encrypting-a-directory-in-linux-746a28709767

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the OS and version you are using. You might have to install EncFS, but as far as I know it has known security issues.